# Why does console.time() show a different time for fetch than the DevTools network tab?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome-devtools

I'm measuring application startup time performance.

I've noticed that the longest part of startup happens where I do an API call to fetch a user. I've wrapped the fetch call with console.time() like this:

```js
            if(options.timing) console.time('get-fetch');
            const response = await fetch(get_url, get_options);
            if(options.timing) console.timeEnd('get-fetch');
```

This reports a time, on average, of around 250-300ms. However, when I look in Chrome DevTools network tab, the time reported for that API request is around 70ms.

I'm curious about the reason why I'd be seeing such a variation in timing.

My theory is that because so much is happening at startup the time slice of the event loop is saturated at that point, which is pushing the local time out for the console.time() calls, due to the fact that it's an async operation and only returning on a later frame. I'm guessing that the network tab timing is accurate, and the 250ms time on console.time() is an illusion caused by js parsing and framework loading etc... does this sound correct?

Comment: Yes, this sounds correct. The callstack has to empty before promises are processed. Not sure what you mean by illusion though. If console.timeEnd returns 250ms, then it really took 250ms.

Comment: @MartinJaskulla by "illusion" I mean that the API call didn't actually take 250ms, it took ~70ms. It was everything else that was happening in that frame that made the console.time() report a longer time, so optimizing the API call would be the wrong path to go down in this case.

Comment: Sounds about right. The network tab is getting timing from an (undoubtedly synchronous) internal call to start an async fetch and when the response hits the final ready state (is complete), the time measurement is, once again, in an unencumbered internal process (probably an entirely different thread). You are comparing that to an async console feature waiting for an async runtime event that is placed "somewhere" into one of the event queues, that is finally followed up by another async console feature. Apples to Bananas probably.

Comment: If you're looking for an end-user perception boost, there are lots of other angles to pursue.

Comment: @RandyCasburn thanks, yes, it seems like that's the problem. I'm using ionic, it's a pretty heavy framework. It lazy loads its components, so they scatter their parsing and loading time across the event loop at startup. In this case, it's making the user API call appear to take longer than it actually does.

Comment: There has been a lot of study about code splitting and lazy loading module code. While it is a bit of an art, it isn't always the best approach. You might consider taking a more direct  tact with that aspect of your app. Bundle up all the initialized components and send them all at once while leaving the other components that don't render above the fold or at initialization. The bundle will be large, but you might be surprise at how much faster your app loads. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

After digging into the profiler, it appears that the theory is correct - the frame where the api call is loading has an extra 82ms added to it from other calls.

I've posted a pic and reference below. For others who are running into this, looking at the frames in the profiler (as below) will help diagnose issues.

[image: performace profile]